# How to set image links for a multipage webpack configuration when the landing page is not in a subdirectory?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, relative-path, webpack-file-loader

I am trying my hand at a multipage webpack configuration and have a question about how to load images differently for a landing page compared to the other pages on the site. The landing page builds to the root directory, while the other pages build to their respective subfolders.

Webpack appends the correct relative path `../images/` for the other pages, however the landing page needs to remain as `images/`, as it is located on the root directory along with the images folder.

How can I configure webpack such that `<img src="images/00.jpg">` stays the same for the landing page, but is updated to `<img src="../images/00.jpg">` for all other pages?

Here is the source folder:

```
/ src /
   -home.html
   -about.html
   js/
      -home.js
      -about.js
   images/
      -00.jpg
      -01.jpg
   scss/
      -style.scss
```

Here is the build folder webpack generates:

```
/ public_html /
   -index.html   // relative links in this file become broken :(
   -bundle.js
   about/
      -index.html
      -bundle.js
   images/
      -00.jpg
      -01.jpg
   css/
      -style.css
```

Finally, here is the webpack configuration. Please excuse the wall of code, I decided to include the entire configuration in case there is a better way to set this up.

```
// webpack.config.js

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
 entry: {
   home: './src/js/home.js',
   about: './src/js/about.js',
  },
 output: {
   filename: (pathData) => {
     return pathData.chunk.name === 'home' ? 'bundle.js' : '[name]/bundle.js';
   },
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public_html')
 },
 module: {
   rules: [
     {
       test: /\.js$/,
       exclude: /node_modules/,
       use: {
         loader: "babel-loader"
       }
     },{
       test: /\.html$/,
       use: [
         {
           loader: "html-loader",
           options: { minimize: true }
         }
       ]
     },{
       test: /\.css$/,
       use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"]
     },{
       test: /\.sass$|\.scss$/,
       use: [
         MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
         { loader: 'css-loader' },
         { loader: 'sass-loader' },
       ],
     },{
       test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
       use: [
         {
           loader: 'file-loader',
           options: {
             name: '[name].[ext]',
             outputPath:'images/',
             publicPath:'../images/'    // how to exclude home.html ?
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   ]
 },
 plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      hash: true,
      filename: 'index.html',      // landing page remains in root directory
      template: 'src/index.html',
      chunks: ['home']
   }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      hash: true,
      filename: 'about/index.html', // all other pages move to subdirectories
      template: 'src/about.html',
      chunks: ['about']
   }),
   new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "css/style.css"
   }),
   new CleanWebpackPlugin()
 ]
};
```

Thank you! And also, let me know how you like this configuration file!

Comment: okay, I'm going to just find and replace `../images/` with `images/` for the landing page's index.html each time I build until I get to the bottom of this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it working. horray!

I never ended up using `publicPath`. Maybe there would have been a way to change it, but this ended up being a red herring. Instead I restructured my `src` directory to follow the pattern I was looking for, and removed `html-loader` so the paths wouldn't get changed during the build process.

Here is my new source directory:

```
/ src /
  -home.html
  templates/
    -about.html
  js/
    -home.js
    -about.js
  images/
    -00.jpg
    -01.jpg
  scss/
    -style.scss
```

You can see `home.html` is purposely on the main directory rather than in `/templates`. Image sources are referenced as `images/` in `home.html`, and `../images/` elsewhere.

Now instead of `html-loader`, I used `copy-webpack-plugin` to require / copy the images from the source directory to the build folder, as `html-loader` was changing the paths during the build process. It took me a few tries to figure out that `html-loader` was the culprit.

Here is my final working webpack config for the record.

```
// webpack.config.js

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
 context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
 entry: {
   home: './js/home.js',
   about: './js/about.js',
  },
 output: {
   filename: (pathData) => {
     return pathData.chunk.name === 'home' ? 'bundle.js' : '[name]/bundle.js';
   },
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public_html')
 },
 module: {
   rules: [
     {
       test: /\.js$/,
       exclude: /node_modules/,
       use: {
         loader: "babel-loader"
       }
     },{
       test: /\.css$/,
       use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"]
     },{
       test: /\.sass$|\.scss$/,
       use: [
         MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
         { loader: 'css-loader' },
         { loader: 'sass-loader' },
       ],
     },{
       test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
       use: [
         {
           loader: 'file-loader',
           options: {
             name: '[path][name].[ext]'
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   ]
 },
 plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {from:'./image',to:'image'} 
      ],
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      hash: true,
      filename: 'index.html',      // landing page remains in root directory
      template: 'index.html',
      chunks: ['home']
   }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      hash: true,
      filename: 'about/index.html', // all other pages move to subdirectories
      template: 'templates/about.html',
      chunks: ['about']
   }),
   new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "style.css"
   }),
   new CleanWebpackPlugin()
 ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem on this Way.

1. Import images on views

`Import YourImage from '../../public/assets/img/your-image.png';`

2. Call where you need with implement them

`src={YourImage}`

Or in your classNames

`` background-image: `url(${YourImage})` ``

3. Config the path to your project repository from GitHub in the rules section of webpack.config.js file.

Repository: "https://maikpwwq.github.io/your-repository/"

`rules: [ { type: "asset", test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|jpeg)$/i, use: [{ options: { publicPath: '/your-repository/'}, loader: 'file-loader' ]} } ]`